# Check if a mail got a reply after a certain amount of time

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, office365

On my work due to the overload of the people I normally need to push people to reply to certain emails. I need to remember manually which emails I've sent without a reply.

Is there a feature, a plugin or a tool to warn me if an email was expected to receive an answer in **X** time units but I didn't get the reply?

Comment: You can flag emails in outlook with a custom amount of time. Also you can right click and add a reminder too

Comment: Good but check that I don't want a reminder to check myself for a reply, I need the reminder to trigger if I haven't received an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Outlook doesn't provide a build-in feature to achieve this. You can add reminders to message you sent to notify yourself even the recipients, you can also request a read receipt in the message. However, no native option available to pop up a reminder automatically for the messages that you haven't received a reply. I found the following article which provided a method to achieve it via VBA, you may have a look at it and see whether it applies to your situation:

[How to Get a Notification If Not Receiving the Reply of a Specific Email within Expected Time](https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/get-notification-not-receiving-reply-specific-email-within-expected-time/)